# How to pick out and multiply odd numbers with each other

Tags: java, random

I'm very beginner at Java. My task is to generate twenty random numbers from 60 to 84 and to pick out and multiply only odd numbers and display it. Right now I'm only able to generate the numbers:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int[] n = new int[20]; 
        Random rnd = new Random (); 
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
            n[i]=rnd.nextInt(84 - 60 + 1) + 60;
            System.out.print (n[i]+" : "); 
        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to multiply all of the odd numbers? you can store the result and check if the generated number is odd then mutiply with the result

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int[] n = new int[20]; 
        Random rnd = new Random (); 
        long result=1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { 
            n[i]=rnd.nextInt(84 - 60 + 1) + 60;
            System.out.print (n[i]+" : "); 
            if(n[i]%2==1)
               result=result*n[i];
        } 
        System.out.print (" Result : " + result); 
    }
}
```

Comment: this code worked well but the result sometimes was in negatives. worked perfectly when chnaged result from `double` to `long`

Comment: Yeah long works better since the result would have been too big

Answer (score 0):

You can generate random numbers between 60-84 using `ThreadLocalRandom` which includes min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)

, Check if the random number is odd and store the multiplication in `mul` variable then display it

[ThreadLocalRandom Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt(int,int))

```
        double mul = 1;
        int rand;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(60, 85);
            if (rand % 2 != 0) {
                mul *= rand;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The multiply of odd numbers between [60-84]: " + mul);
```